# How to find max value from a group by aggregate function in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How to find max value from a group by aggregate function in mongodb? I wanted to find out Biggest Total Amount and its correspondant Bill No.

Code snip is given bellow:

```js
db.PurchaseDetails.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$Items" },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": 
            {
              "BillNo":"$BillNo",
              "DateP":"$DateP", 
              "Type":"$Type"
            },       
            "Total": {"$sum": "$Items.Total"}
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the highest total amount with its corresponding Bill No, you need a further **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline where you re-order the aggregated documents by their total amount key descending, and then group the ordered documents together to get the highest amount and its corresponding bill number using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)** operator. Something like the following should suffice:

```
db.PurchaseDetails.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$Items" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "BillNo":"$BillNo",
                "DateP":"$DateP", 
                "Type":"$Type"
            },       
            "Total": {"$sum": "$Items.Total"}
        }   
    },
    { "$sort": { "Total": -1 } }, // re-order the aggregated documents by the Total field 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null, // group all the documents
            "MaximumTotal": { "$first": "$Total" }, // get the maximum total
            "BillNo": { "$first": "$_id.BillNo" } // get the corresponding Bill No.
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this outside the group

`maxTotal: { $max: "$Total" }`

Comment: Not able to get the proper result. Can u paste entire code here?